# jq - How to escape ' * ' (special character) in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, jq

Im using the following command in shell script

```
echo $(jq -n '"1\n2\n3" | gsub("\n"; @t " * ")')
```

and the expected output is

```
"1 * 2 * 3"
```

But in shell script it replaces '\n' with all the file names in the respective directory (i.e '*' is treated as a special parameter in this context).

```
1 file1 file2 2 file1 file2 3
```

When we execute the same in a terminal it gives the expected output.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the substitution?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh my gosh I missed that. After adding that it worked. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `echo` at all?  Just run `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the command substitution to prevent the result (`1 * 2 * 3`) from undergoing pathname expansion.

```
echo "$(jq -n '"1\n2\n3" | gsub("\n"; @t " * ")')"
```

Keep in mind, though, that there is no reason capture the output of a command if the *only* thing you do with it is pass it as the lone argument to `echo`. Just let the command run by itself.

```
$ echo "$(jq -n '"1\n2\n3" | gsub("\n"; @t " * ")')"
"1 * 2 * 3"
$ jq -n '"1\n2\n3" | gsub("\n"; @t " * ")'
"1 * 2 * 3"
```

(As a bonus, `jq` will probably produce colored output if you aren't capturing the output.)

Comment: I am facing the same kind of weird issue, declared cron expression to be passed to rest API curl call, "0 0 9 * * ?" is converted to "0 0 9 somestring somestring ?"
I am using the jq library.